# How to make content div WITH background image (inside wrapper) to stretch 100% height, while having sticky footer?

Tags: css, height, sticky-footer

Yeah I know the topic was explained probably million times, but have a look at this. I cant make `#content` and/or `.content-bg` go all the way down and show the pattern down to the bottom:

```css
html, body {
  height: 100%;
}

body {
  min-width: 500px;
  margin: 0px;
  padding: 0px;
}

#wrapper {
  position: relative;
  width: 100%;
  min-height: 100%;
  height: auto !important;
  margin: 0px auto -97px;
}

#header {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100px;
  position: relative;
  background-color: #ccc;
}

#content {
min-height: 100%;
}

.content-bg {
background: url("http://www.squidfingers.com/_patterns/files/pattern_136.gif") repeat scroll 0% 0% #F9EDE4;
overflow: hidden;
}

#footer {
background-color: #ccc;
height: 97px;
}
```

```html
<body>
  <div id="wrapper">
    <div id="header">
      header content
    </div>
    <div id="content">
      <div class="content-bg">
        content
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div id="footer">
    footer content
  </div>
</body>
```

Any ideas?

Comment: did you tried background-size:cover?

Comment: @K.B.M that changes nothing. The thing is that pattern is applied normally but I can't make div 100% height.

Comment: Then what does "to stretch 100% height " mean? Here if parent div is having 100% height, then bg also get expanded.. now parent div is not having 100% height.. so you are not able to stretch..explain clearly what you want

Comment: @K.B.M I want to make that pattern to fill the whole page down to the footer. Now `content` div depends on its content only, but I need it go to the bottom not depending on content.